# Conditional BeforeInsert Trigger

Tags: apex, before-trigger

I have some issue with my trigger and can not sort it out.  
It exists 4 recordType (RT1, RT2, RT3, RT4) and I don't want trigger firing when recordType is RT4.

Description :

> This trigger call an apex class
>     to  modify the owner on the CAP Customer by the corresponding Sales Rep related to the  Account

Code :

```
trigger CAPCustomerBeforeInsert on CAPCustomer__c (before insert) {

if (PAD.canTrigger('TR003AssignCAPCustomerOwner')){
PAD.myLog('CAPCustomer Before insert <<< run by ' + UserInfo.getName());    
PAD.logLimits();

//TR003 :
//whene inserting a cap customer

PAD.myLog('TR003AssignCAPCustomerOwner.AssignCAPCustomerOwnerBySalesRep BEGIN');

PAD.myLog('Nb of cap customer to treat:'+Trigger.new.size());
TR003AssignCAPCustomerOwner.AssignCAPCustomerOwnerBySalesRep(Trigger.new); 

PAD.myLog('TR003AssignCAPCustomerOwner.AssignCAPCustomerOwnerBySalesRep END');

PAD.logLimits();
} 
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What s your question exactly? You don't *ask* anything. What behavior do you expect? What behavior do you observe?

Comment: @AdrianLarson I think the OP doesn't want the trigger to do anything when the CapCustomer object recordtype is 'RT4'. Thats what I got from the question.

Comment: @AdrianLarson U true my expect is "I don't want trigger firing when recordType is RT4"

Comment: @Mahmood 
Let me check and come back to you. Thanks

Comment: @Mahmood yhanks a lot. It works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put a check in your trigger to achieve that

```
List<CAPCustomer__c> ccList = new List<CAPCustomer__c>();
for (CAPCustomer__c cc : trigger.new){
 if (cc.recordtypeid != Schema.SObjectType.CAPCustomer__c.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('RT4').getRecordTypeId() ) ccList.add(cc);
// end of for loop
}
// now you have a list of Cap Custom object record that donot belong to RT4

// let the trigger do stuff
// finally
TR003AssignCAPCustomerOwner.AssignCAPCustomerOwnerBySalesRep(ccList); 
}
```